# Laplace transform of : $t^{\gamma-1} F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,\frac{t}{d})$, where $F$ is the Gauss' hypergeometric function

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of : $t^{\gamma-1} F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,\frac{t}{d})$, where $\gamma >0 $ and $F$ is the Gauss' hypergeometric function.

Note that I have the Laplace transform of : $t^{\gamma-1} F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,-t)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although M. W. Alomari's result is correct, the reasoning is critically flawed.

First, the power series representation for the Gauss hypergeometric function F (also denoted $_2F_1$) is **not** defined (or is infinity) when neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ is a negative integer and $|t|>|d|$. As the Laplace transform consists in integrating along the positive half-line, an undefined function (except for the [0,|d|] segment) is being integrated in M. W. Alomari's answer; this does not make sense.

Second, generalized hypergeometric functions $_pF_q$ just do **not** converge as power series for $p > q+1$ (see [1]).

There is one exception for polynomials, when at least one of the first two parameters is a negative integer. Then $_3F_1$ as a series makes sense as a polynomial, as the series terminates.

Otherwise you must use Mellin-Barnes integrals along a Bromwich path, or at least a Euler-type integral representations, see [2]. You will arrive at the same result, with different intermediate steps (basically the same argument comes into play, except that you have integrals instead of series).

Then if you want to use generalized hypergeometic power *series*, $_3F_1$ may be expressed as a combination of confluent hypergeometric functions of the first kind and a hypergeometric function $_2F_2$ in the simple case of $\gamma=1$ and $d=1$. Otherwise you need three $_2F_2$ functions. These two kinds of hypergeometric functions have power series representations, unlike $_3F_1$.

As an incidental note, one has to suppose that $\delta$ is not a negative or null integer for the question to make sense. With this extra assumption, the result given by *Mathematica* is:

$$  
\frac{(1-\delta) \left[\, _{2}F_{2}(1,2-\delta ;2-\alpha ,2-\beta ;-s)\right]}{(\alpha -1) (\beta -1)}+\frac{\pi  \Gamma (\delta ) \left(\frac{e^{-i \pi  \beta } \csc(\pi  \beta ) s^{\beta } \Gamma (\alpha -\beta ) \, _{1}F_{1}(\beta -\delta +1;-\alpha +\beta +1;-s)}{\Gamma (\delta -\beta )}+\frac{e^{-i \pi  \alpha } \csc(\pi  \alpha )  s^{\alpha } \Gamma (\beta -\alpha ) \, _{1}F_{1}(\alpha -\delta +1;\alpha -\beta +1;-s)}{\Gamma (\delta -\alpha )}\right)}{s \Gamma (\alpha ) \Gamma (\beta )}
$$
if:
$$\\
\gamma = 1 \land d = 1 \land (\alpha,\beta) \notin \mathbb{Z}^2 \land (\delta-\alpha,\delta-\beta) \notin \mathbb{Z^-}^2 \land \Re(\alpha +\beta -\delta) <1 \land \space\space \Re(s) > 0.
$$
and in the general case:
$$
\Gamma (\delta ) \left(\frac{(-d)^{\alpha } \Gamma (\beta -\alpha ) \Gamma (\gamma -\alpha ) s^{\alpha -\gamma } \, _2F_2(\alpha ,\alpha -\delta +1;\alpha -\beta +1,\alpha -\gamma +1;-d s)}{\Gamma (\beta ) \Gamma (\delta -\alpha )}+\frac{\frac{(-d)^{\beta } \Gamma (\alpha -\beta ) \Gamma (\gamma -\beta ) s^{\beta -\gamma } \, _2F_2(\beta ,\beta -\delta +1;-\alpha +\beta +1,\beta -\gamma +1;-d s)}{\Gamma (\delta -\beta )}+\frac{\Gamma (\gamma ) (-d)^{\gamma } \Gamma (\alpha -\gamma ) \Gamma (\beta -\gamma ) \, _2F_2(\gamma ,\gamma -\delta +1;-\alpha +\gamma +1,-\beta +\gamma +1;-d s)}{\Gamma (\beta ) \Gamma (\delta -\gamma )}}{\Gamma (\alpha )}\right)
$$
if: 
$$
(\Re(d)<0\lor d\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Re(\gamma )>0 \land (\alpha,\beta, \gamma) \notin \mathbb{Z}^3 \land (\delta-\alpha,\delta-\beta, \delta-\gamma) \notin \mathbb{Z^-}^3 \land \space\space \Re(s) > 0
$$
There is no such thing as a "closed-form" solution without some generalized hypergeometric functions around, unless you want to use the even more sophisticated Merjer-G or Fox-H functions, but I guess this is not what you want.

---

$[1]$ *NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, Cambridge University Press, Olver and alii, $2010$, p. $404$, $16.2$(iv)

$[2]$ NIST p. $408$, §$16.5$, or Slater's classic book *Generalized Hypergeometric Series*, Cambridge University Press, $1966$, pages $22$ to $25$

Answer (score 1):

Since $F\left( {\alpha ,\beta ,\delta ;t} \right) = \sum {\frac{{\left( \alpha  \right)_n \left( \beta  \right)_n }}{{n!\left( \delta  \right)_n }}t^n } 
$. Assuming the uniform convergence of the series,  then term by term integration yields that 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - st} } t^{\gamma  - 1} F\left( {\alpha ,\beta ,\delta ;t} \right)dt
\\
 &= \int_0^\infty  {e^{ - st} } t^{\gamma  - 1} \left( {\sum {\frac{{\left( \alpha  \right)_n \left( \beta  \right)_n }}{{n!\left( \delta  \right)_n }}t^n } } \right)dt
\\
&= \sum {\frac{{\left( \alpha  \right)_n \left( \beta  \right)_n }}{{n!\left( \delta  \right)_n }}\left( {\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - st} } t^{n + \gamma  - 1} dt} \right)} 
\\
&= \sum {\frac{{\left( \alpha  \right)_n \left( \beta  \right)_n }}{{n!\left( \delta  \right)_n }}\frac{{\Gamma \left( {n + \gamma } \right)}}{{s^{n + \gamma } }}} 
\end{align}
where $$
\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - st} } t^{n + \gamma  - 1} dt = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {n + \gamma } \right)}}{{s^{n + \gamma } }}
,$$ valid if $n+\gamma-1>-1$.  To write the answer in more general form, we may use the generalized Hypergeometric function as follows:$$
_p F_q \left( {a_1 ,a_2 , \ldots ,a_p ;b_1 ,b_2 , \ldots ,b_q ;t} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {a_1 } \right)_n \left( {a_2 } \right)_n  \cdots \left( {a_p } \right)_n }}{{\left( {b_1 } \right)_n \left( {b_2 } \right)_n  \cdots \left( {b_q } \right)_n }}\frac{{t^n }}{{n!}}} 
,$$ so in our case we have $
p = 3,q = 1,a_1  = \alpha ,a_2  = \beta ,a_3  = \gamma ,b_1  = \delta ,t = \frac{1}{s}
$ and since $
\left( \alpha  \right)_n  = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha  + n} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)}}
$, then we may write the above series as:
\begin{align}
\sum {\frac{{\left( \alpha  \right)_n \left( \beta  \right)_n }}{{n!\left( \delta  \right)_n }}\frac{{\Gamma \left( {n + \gamma } \right)}}{{s^{n + \gamma } }}}  &= \frac{{\Gamma \left( \delta  \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)\Gamma \left( \beta  \right)}}
\sum {\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha  + n} \right)\Gamma \left( {\beta  + n} \right)}}{{n!\Gamma \left( {\delta  + n} \right)}}\frac{{\Gamma \left( {n + \gamma } \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \gamma  \right)}}\frac{{\Gamma \left( \gamma  \right)}}{{s^{n + \gamma } }}} 
\\
 & = 
\frac{{\Gamma \left( \delta  \right)\Gamma \left( \gamma  \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)\Gamma \left( \beta  \right)}}s^\gamma  \sum {\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha  + n} \right)\Gamma \left( {\beta  + n} \right)}}{{n!\Gamma \left( {\delta  + n} \right)}}\frac{1}{{s^n }}} 
\\
&= \frac{{\Gamma \left( \delta  \right)\Gamma \left( \gamma  \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)\Gamma \left( \beta  \right)}}s^\gamma \cdot 
{}_3 F_1 \left( {\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma ;\delta ;\frac{1}{s}} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. but I need a closed-form solution or a method to evaluate this infinite sum..

Comment: @whuber any hint? (please)

Comment: I added more details in the answer; hope this hopeful.

Comment: -How did you extract $ \frac { \Gamma(\delta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}$ from the sum ?

Comment: So I think you should put $\Gamma(\alpha+n)$ instead of $(\alpha)_n$

Comment: I made a correction, see the answer  now. In the original sum we have $\left( \alpha  \right)_n  = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha  + n} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)}}$, similarly we have the same thing for $\beta, \delta$, so that substitute these quantities in the summation you got the result

Comment: In the sum you should replace $\Gamma(\alpha)$ by $\Gamma(\alpha+n)$

Comment: Right. I lost my focus

Comment: OK great. I have one more question (Plz): do you make any assumptions about the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\delta$ (integers for ex. ? ..)

Comment: There is no assumption  on the parameters $\alpha,beta,\gamma$. However, you have to be careful about the convergence of the series. It is well know that the hypergeometirc differential equation has a singular points at $0,1,\infty$ and each of which has different interval of convergence. You may refer to a D.E. book

Comment: I think to guarantee the convergence you will need to add assumptions on the parameters.

Comment: $_{3}F_1$ **cannot** be represented as a series and you **may not** change the order of the integral and the sum. So your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: @user12030145  You're absolutely right.